# ussp-push file not found

Tags: linux, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I am getting a file not found error when attempting a ussp-push from Linux command line on a Raspberry Pi.

The command I am attempting is:

`ussp-push /dev/rfcomm0 latestImage.jpg file.jpeg`

You can see here this is the proper usage: http://www.stlinux.com/kernel/bluetooth/Obex-ussp-push

What is unusual is whether or not my local file exists (i.e. latestImage.jpg) I still get the same error: `Can't find file file.jpg`. The destination file should be the name you want to give the local image you are sending over Bluetooth on the remote file system (i.e. it shouldn't matter).

I have attempted various different possible names for the destination and source files but nothing seems to work.